# Are GoDaddy dedicated managed servers HIPAA compliant?

Tags: godaddy, hipaa

I keep getting the run around from godaddy regarding HIPAA compliance.

Does anyone have a researched answer on this matter?  We have dedicated 5505 and dedicated server with them and I wanted to know if it is possible to make this setup HIPAA/HITECH compliant.

I'm a bit hesitant because when I asked them what the Business Associate agreement with them, they responded, "what is that?"

Comment: Only GoDaddy can answer this, but having worked with HIPAA compliance in the past, I'd guess that they're very unlikely to be compliant unless it's a specific, special service.

Comment: This response should be more than enough to convince you they are not what you are looking for.

Comment: If I google for hipaa managed hosting, I get pages full of results that smell of expensive boutique hosters from Google to Germany. If any mainstream hoster was willing to compete in that era they would hardly leave these results to specialty shops...

Comment: _they responded - what is that?_ You answered your own question. If you ask someone if they're HIPAA, SOX, or PCI compliant and they don't know, then they aren't. It's just that simple. They obviously don't know about the hoop jumping and certification. Good network and server security is a subset of the above, which they more than likely meet, the added expense of compliance is above and beyond their business arena.

Comment: Amazon's AWS has HIPAA compliant clients. Take a look there.

Comment: What this boils down to is that you cannot expect low cost hosting to provide high cost services.

Comment: lol - too localized?  i think this would have helped a lot of people.  especially the people that are setting up PHI in hosted environments.  very especially the ones who did it for the organization i am trying to remediate.

Comment: I found this question to be very helpful for research I am doing. Please rethink your reasons for closing it!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Go Daddy Managed servers cannot be made HIPAA complaint.  HIPAA requires a DC inspection which will not be possible with our data centers.

Comment: This would seem to be a definitive answer.